# fbBatchedBridge is undefined

Tags: reactjs, npm, react-native, ecmascript-6, babeljs

The application was compilable before I started experimenting with the babel compiler and adding/removing node modules. Now it can't connect to the development server.

The error:

> Unable to execute JS call: _fbBatchedBridge is undefined

The only strange thing is this React Packager line (only 1 dependency, 14ms) that suggests it may not crawl dependencies at all:

```
<START> find dependencies
transformed 1/1 (100%)
<END>   find dependencies (14ms)
```

- Similar error on both [iOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PSuaF.png) and [Android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBGNB.png) devices.
- Both in simulator and on device.
- The URL is accessible.
- Wiping extra lines in `package.json`, `.babelrc` and `index.js` didn't help, which suggests something else may be wrong.
- Editing `AppDelegate.m` and `react-native-xcode.sh` didn't help, as other answers suggested.

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "ReactProject",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel": "^6.5.2",
    "babel-core": "^6.1.2",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-jsx": "^6.8.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-async-to-generator": "^6.8.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.1.2",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.9.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.1.2",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.11.1",
    "babel-preset-react-native-stage-0": "^1.0.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.1.2",
    "babel-preset-stage-3": "^6.11.0",
    "babylon": "^6.8.2",
    "cross-spawn-async": "^2.2.4",
    "minimatch": "^3.0.2",
    "react": "^15.1.0",
    "react-native": "^0.28.0",
    "react-native-accordion": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-geocoder": "^0.4.2",
    "react-native-maps": "^0.6.0",
    "react-native-orientation": "^1.17.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^2.2.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^2.0.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-native-cli": "^1.0.0"
  }
}
```

.babelrc:

```
{
  "presets": [ "react", "es2015", "react-native-stage-0" ],
  "plugins": ["transform-async-to-generator", "transform-react-jsx"]
}
```

React Packager (full):

```
[5:02:27 PM] <START> Building Dependency Graph
[5:02:27 PM] <START> Crawling File System
[Hot Module Replacement] Server listening on /hot

React packager ready.
[5:02:29 PM] <END>   Crawling File System (2116ms)
[5:02:29 PM] <START> Building in-memory fs for JavaScript
[5:02:29 PM] <END>   Building in-memory fs for JavaScript (143ms)
[5:02:29 PM] <START> Building in-memory fs for Assets
[5:02:29 PM] <END>   Building in-memory fs for Assets (73ms)
[5:02:29 PM] <START> Building Haste Map
[5:02:29 PM] <START> Building (deprecated) Asset Map
[5:02:29 PM] <END>   Building (deprecated) Asset Map (86ms)
[5:02:30 PM] <END>   Building Haste Map (254ms)
[5:02:30 PM] <END>   Building Dependency Graph (2596ms)
[5:02:30 PM] <START> request:/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true
[5:02:30 PM] <START> find dependencies
transformed 1/1 (100%)
[5:02:30 PM] <END>   find dependencies (13ms)
[5:02:30 PM] <END>   request:/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true (50ms)
```